# Terraform skip null for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am setting tags to AMI. I have ubuntu and EKS AMI, where EKS AMI needs to be set with k8s version, containerd etc which are not required for other OS. I have declared all variables that are EKS specific to default to null in an assumption that they will skipped while I run for_each but it errors out. Here is the code and error.

```
locals {

  tags = {
    docker_version = var.docker_version
    kubernetes = var.k8s_version
    cni_plugin_version = var.cni_plugin_version
    containerd_version = var.containerd_version
    target = var.target
    source_ami_id = var.source_ami_id
    Release = var.ami_release-version
    Description = var.ami_description
    Name = var.ami_name
    Creator = var.creator
  }

data "aws_ami" "ami_image" {
  most_recent      = true
  owners           = ["xxxxxxxx"]
  name_regex = var.ami_regex
}

output "ami_id" {
  value = data.aws_ami.ami_image.id
}
output "ami_arn" {
  value = data.aws_ami.ami_image.arn
}
output "ami_name" {
  value = data.aws_ami.ami_image.name
}

resource "aws_ec2_tag" "ami-taggging" {
  resource_id = data.aws_ami.ami_image.id
  for_each    = local.tags
  key         = each.key
  value       = each.value
}
```

Error when values are null:

```
Error: Missing required argument
  on main.tf line 41, in resource "aws_ec2_tag" "ami-tagging":
  41:   value       = each.value
```

Is there a way to skip or gracefully move to next record if the value is null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `default_tags` (not shown in your question) is similar to your `local.tag`, you could do the following:

```
resource "aws_ec2_tag" "ami-taggging" {
  resource_id = data.aws_ami.ami_image.id
  for_each    = {for k,v in local.tags: k => v if v != null}
  key         = each.key
  value       = each.value
}
```

The solution uses [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html). Basically, it takes your original `local.tags` and creates new temporary map that will be used in the `for_each`. The new map will have same keys and values (k=>v) except those that don't meet the `if` condition.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the code. I will try the code.

Comment: Now that the k,v is used should key = each.k and value = each.v ?

Comment: @Raj each.key and each.value are fine. Why? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The code above works. Just out of curiosity about the logic.

Comment: @Raj Glad it works. If so, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @marchin can you explain 
```
for_each    = {for k,v in local.default_tags: k => v if v != null}
```

Comment: @Raj Updated the answer with explenation.